# Can Json Schema Validation via Newtonsoft.Json.Schema validate VALUES?

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0, json.net

I have a small sample.  If my Json is good, it works correctly.  If I change the "tag" (aka, the property name), it works correctly by having invalid messages.  If I change the value of a Guid to be a non-guid-value, the Json Schema Validation does not fail.

Is there a way to fail validation for a Guid value?

```
public class MyCoolObject
{
    public Guid TheUuid { get; set; }

    public Int32 TheInteger { get; set; }

    public DateTime TheDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

and my test method.  When i = 2 (and I'm setting the string to contain "NOTAGUID-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"), that is when I don't get error messages like I would like to.

```
    private static void RunJsonSchemaValidate()
    {

        /* Note, the TheUuid is of type "string" and format "guid" */
        string jsonSchemaText = @"
                {
                  ""typeName"": ""MyCoolObject"",
                  ""additionalProperties"": false,
                  ""type"": ""object"",
                  ""required"": [
                    ""TheUuid"",
                    ""TheInteger"",
                    ""TheDateTime""
                  ],
                  ""properties"": {
                    ""TheUuid"": {
                      ""type"": ""string"",
                      ""format"": ""guid""
                    },
                    ""TheInteger"": {
                      ""type"": ""integer""
                    },
                    ""TheDateTime"": {
                      ""type"": ""string"",
                      ""format"": ""date-time""
                    }
                  },
                  ""$schema"": ""http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#""
                }
        ";

        Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema jschem = Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchema.Parse(jsonSchemaText);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {

            string jsonContent = string.Empty;

            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    /* bad json, change the property NAME */
                    jsonContent = @"{
                        ""TheUuidXXX"": ""33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"",
                        ""TheInteger"": 2147483647,
                        ""TheDateTime"": ""2017-08-22T15:32:10.7023008-04:00""
                    }";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    /* bad json, change the property VALUE */
                    jsonContent = @"{
                        ""TheUuid"": ""NOTAGUID-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"",
                        ""TheInteger"": 2147483647,
                        ""TheDateTime"": ""2017-08-22T15:32:10.7023008-04:00""
                    }";
                    break;
                case 3:
                    /* bad json, bad integer */
                    jsonContent = @"{
                        ""TheUuid"": ""33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"",
                        ""TheInteger"": notAnumber,
                        ""TheDateTime"": ""2017-08-22T15:32:10.7023008-04:00""
                    }";
                    break;
                case 4:
                    /* bad json, bad date */
                    jsonContent = @"{
                        ""TheUuid"": ""33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"",
                        ""TheInteger"": 2147483647,
                        ""TheDateTime"": ""NOTADATE""
                    }";
                    break;
                default:
                    /* good json */
                    jsonContent = @"{
                        ""TheUuid"": ""33333333-3333-3333-3333-333333333333"",
                        ""TheInteger"": 2147483647,
                        ""TheDateTime"": ""2017-08-22T15:32:10.7023008-04:00""
                    }";
                    break;

            }

            /* START THE MEAT OF THIS PROCEDURE */

            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jobj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonContent);

            IList<string> messages;
            bool valid = jobj.IsValid(jschem, out messages);

            /* ENDTHE MEAT OF THIS PROCEDURE */


            if (!valid)
            {
                string errorMsg = "i=" + i.ToString() + ":" + string.Join(",", messages);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine(errorMsg);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
                Console.WriteLine("i=" + i.ToString() + ":" + "Good json Yes");

                MyCoolObject thisShouldWorkWhenValidationPasses = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCoolObject>(jsonContent);

            }

            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
            Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------");
            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);


        }
```

and the packages

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>

  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="10.0.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json.Schema" version="3.0.3" targetFramework="net45" />

</packages>
```

So what is happening is that when i=2, the json-schema passes, but then MyCoolObject thisShouldWorkWhenValidationPasses throws an exception....

> i=2:Good json Yes
>
> Unhandled Exception: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error
>   converting value "NOTAGUID-3333-3333-3333-333333333333" to type
>   'System.Guid'. Path 'TheUuid', line 2, position 77. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String
>   to System.Guid.

:(

I'm trying to have the json-schema fail earlier.

The end-game is to perform a json-schema-validation without exceptions getting thrown.  Then after "everything is clear" try to load the objects.  My real stuff is more complex, but this small demo shows the issue(s).

I also ***replaced*** the "meat of this procedure" with the below code

```
            /* START THE MEAT OF THIS PROCEDURE */

            Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader reader = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader(new System.IO.StringReader(jsonContent));

            Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchemaValidatingReader validatingReader = new Newtonsoft.Json.Schema.JSchemaValidatingReader(reader);
            validatingReader.Schema = JSchema.Parse(schemaJson);

            IList<string> messages = new List<string>();
            validatingReader.ValidationEventHandler += (o, a) => messages.Add(a.Message);

            Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
            /* below is the issue with this code..you still try to serialize the object...and that can throw an exception */
            MyCoolObject p = serializer.Deserialize<MyCoolObject>(validatingReader);
            bool valid = !messages.Any();

            /* END THE MEAT OF THIS PROCEDURE */
```

But again, this is subject to exceptions being thrown .. trying to validate.

Comment: Why, though? If you could expect most JSON to, in fact, be valid, then first checking the schema, then deserializing does all the parsing twice. Avoiding exceptions for cases that aren't exceptional is a good idea, but in this case I'd think *invalid* JSON is the exceptional case, as we expect machines to produce it. If you do want to avoid exception handling for some reason, you can use `JsonSerializerSettings.Error`.

Comment: I have a http-web-service that accepts json.  the "client' can send any json they want.  if the json does not validate, i want them to have instance-feedback (aka, a (bad) response to the original request).  if they give me all-good json, then I stored it and process it async.  I don't care if I have to parse it twice in that case... it will be later in the process.

Comment: Well, the only way to guarantee the deserialization will succeed is to perform it (optionally with an error delegate). Schemas won't help you in all cases because JSON Schema simply isn't designed to handle all the underlying limits of potentially-valid-but-out-of-domain values. In particular, "GUID" isn't a JSON type, because it isn't in JavaScript. `null`, `boolean`, `object`, `array`, `number`, `string` are, but even for things like `number`, range checks are explicitly not part of schema validation. See also [the general docs](http://json-schema.org/documentation.html).

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback Jeroen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jeroen Mostert for the hint that led me to this solution:

```
            /* START THE MEAT OF THIS PROCEDURE */

            IList<string> deserializeMessages = new List<string>();

            /* first get any serialization issues */
            MyCoolObject p = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyCoolObject>(jsonContent,
                new JsonSerializerSettings
                {
                    Error = delegate (object sender, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs args)
                    {
                        deserializeMessages.Add(args.ErrorContext.Error.Message);
                        args.ErrorContext.Handled = true;
                    }
                });

            IList<string> jsonSchemaMessages = new List<string>();
            bool jsonSchemaIsValid = true;
            /* now, only if there were no serialization issues, look at the schema */
            if (!deserializeMessages.Any())
            {
                Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jobj = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonContent);
                jsonSchemaIsValid = jobj.IsValid(jschem, out jsonSchemaMessages);
            }

            IEnumerable<string> allMessages = deserializeMessages.Union(jsonSchemaMessages);

            bool overallValid = !allMessages.Any();

            /* END THE MEAT OF THIS PROCEDURE */
```

This gives me the desired output for this situation:

> i=0:Good json Yes
>
> ---
>
> i=1:Property 'TheUuidXXX' has not been defined and the schema does not
>   allow additional properties. Path 'TheUuidXXX', line 2, position
>   41.,Required properties are missing from object: TheUuid. Path '', line 1, position 1.
>
> ---
>
> i=2:Error converting value "NOTAGUID-3333-3333-3333-333333333333" to
>   type 'System.Guid'. Path 'TheUuid', line 2, position 77.
>
> ---
>
> i=3:Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: o. Path
>   'TheInteger', line 3, position 41.,Error parsing boolean value. Path
>   'TheInteger', line 3, position 42.
>
> ---
>
> i=4:Could not convert string to DateTime: NOTADATE. Path
>   'TheDateTime', line 4, position 50.
>
> ---
>
> PRESS ENTER TO EXIT

I'm still wrapping my head around it a little.  But in my specific situation (where I want to Response back to the http request immediately there was a json issue), it works.

I won't mark this as "the answer" in case anyone comes up with something better.

Note, I changed my i for loop to be < 5

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

Comment: The only way to significantly improve on this is to not deserialize into any objects but immediately discard the results of every sub-object on reading, so you can save on memory in the validation phase in case the JSON is very large. As far as I know you can't (easily) do that with `Newtonsoft.Json`, though, and it stands to reason you would *definitely* not want to do the whole parsing twice if in fact you were expecting huge requests (if only because, at the very least, the whole request needs to be buffered). Validation up front is nice, but not at any cost.